# Are there commands to navigate the NERDTree File Prompt

Tags: vim, nerdtree

When I want to rename a file in NERDTree, I would normally Hit `m` to open the menu, then `m` to move. This opens a prompt as below:

[image]

Now let's say I want to change the folder from `add-friend` to `create-friend`. If this was a normal command prompt which use GNU ReadLine (see [Navigating the Commandline](https://dwmkerr.com/effective-shell-part-1-navigating-the-command-line/)) then I could hit:

- `alt+b` - go back one word
- `alt+b` - go back one word
- `alt+b` - go back one word
- `alt+b` - go back one word
- `alt+d` - delete one word
- `create` - enter the text create

Just like this:

[image]

However none of these shortcuts work as we're really just in a Vim buffer. But I also can't just use standard Vim commands (`?add` then `cw+create` or something) to change the text.

My question is - is there a way to quickly manipulate text on the NERDTree menu prompt? Given how easy it is to jump around in a GNU Readline prompt, or in Vim itself, it always jars when I have to mash the arrow keys when moving or manipulating files!

Thanks in advance!

P.S: If there is a command, I'll be more than happy to PR the README for NERDTree. If there's not a way to do it I'd be happy to try and add one!

Answer (score 0):

You are not in a Vim buffer. You are in the command-line in command-line mode where `:help cmdline-editing` applies, modulo some weird behavior probably caused by an abuse of `:help nr2char()`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you've already figured it out 4 years later, but anyways.
Add this to your .vimrc:

```
" ---------- Emacs-like shortcuts in command line mode ----------
" start of line
:cnoremap <C-a>  <Home>
" back one character
:cnoremap <C-b> <Left>
" delete character under cursor
:cnoremap <C-d> <Del>
" end of line
:cnoremap <C-e> <End>
" forward one character
" Note / TODO: <C-f> remap below overrides standard mapping
" for opening command-line window, maybe it's better not to do so.
:cnoremap <C-f> <Right>
" recall newer command-line
:cnoremap <C-n> <Down>
" recall previous (older) command-line
:cnoremap <C-p> <Up>
" back one word
:cnoremap <M-b> <S-Left>
" forward one word
:cnoremap <M-f> <S-Right>
" ---------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Note:** I couldn't figure out how to make Alt-b / Alt-f consider slash a word separator. Theoretically it can be done via `:set iskeyword-=\/` or `:set iskeyword-=47`, but didn't work for me.
If someone knows how to fix it, please share your knowledge.